# How do I install simplejson 3.3.1 for a Python project in Netbeans IDE 7.3.1

Tags: python, json, netbeans

I am trying to install simplejson-3.3.1.tar.gz so it can be accessed by my Python project in netbeans IDE 7.3.1.

I installed json.py in my src as a quick fix, but need more functionality.

I am using linus mint 15 as an OS.

I am unsure how to get my modules in netbeans to "see" methors e.g. json.dumps.

I am new to netbeans and would appreciate your assistance.

Thanks and regards,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Python setuptools

   sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
2. Now using `pip` install simplejson

   sudo pip install simplejson

In general most Python packages can be installed this way.

Comment: I appreciate your assistance; however, my difficulty is with the netbeans IDE. I have created a new project for python and don't know how to navigate the IDE to ensure that my version and path are correct. My command line python works fine and is 2.7.4 however, my IDE gives me errors with json.batchs(), indicating either the version on command line is not the one I am using with netbeans or I am not specifying the paths properly in net beans. I appreciate your  further assistance, Chris

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue ...

netbeans defaults to jython. I had to save my project files to another directory, delete my project (changing to python 2.7. for current project had no effect) and create a new project with netbeans with python 2.7 as the default.

Thanks for helping me get simplejson into my python 2.7 Nipun! Chris